# powerbi how to create family trees/Hierarchy Chart with multiple children

Tags: powerbi, customization, hierarchy, family-tree

This [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VVV7WwSPDsA) shows how to create family trees/Hierarchy Chart in powerBI using the [Hierarchy Chart Custom Viz by Akvelon](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/power-bi-visuals/WA104381333). It shows how a node could have a multiple parents. But is there a way to have multiple children for the same parent?

Visual diagram:

[image]

In case of the above example I would like to show that `Jeffrey Knight` and `Sandra Knight` have one more son called `my brother`.

Reproducible data for problem (Insert in Advanced Editor for Power Query)

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("jY5dC4IwFIb/yti1wqbp7DaEoA8IvFxeDDo2oZaMFfjvO5uJ2Y3BYOfdnufdpKScRrSEV2vI3rRX7TDytRAx7un5yViSr3Cs4NbQOpI0wXDsycY+nAYb4IL9wOOl51MvK3Ox6rs/C0o2KDmOJ2XBuGD4hh00jYV+pqReEYNSzJUsxE6R6t46HXDO4gRJnHFtLf6gm/j8c2b6fw0xvnAAWKaLqX+Zr98=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [#"Self ID" = _t, Name = _t, Years = _t, #"Parent ID" = _t, Relationship = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Self ID", Int64.Type}, {"Name", type text}, {"Years", type text}, {"Parent ID", type text}, {"Relationship", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

I am not sure how to have two arrows starting from `Jeffrey Knight` which is already present in the data. Duplicate rows does not work as powerbi throws an error if two values are identical in the Id column: `"items have the same id"`.

```
Self Id   Name              Years   Parent Id   Relationship
1         Devin Knight      xxxx-   3&4         self
2         my brother        xxxx-   3&4         brother
3         Sandra Knight     xxxx-               Parent
4         Jeffrey Knight    xxxx-               Parent
```

###########update 1

if there is any dax coding that could help then please provide the suggestions

##############update 2

this is how the data should look like. Row with `self id` 3 and 4 indicate a parent with two children. If we enter data this way then the powerbi throws error and I am looking for suggestions

[image]

Comment: Can you review my edits and let me know if this works with you for intended outcome? This is a really interesting question but wanted to make sure you supplied enough information so that the community could work towards a solid answer.

Comment: why do you have dotted lines coming from `jeffrey knight`?

Comment: That's the primary focus of your question I believed - 1 parent, 2 children?

Comment: also you need to adjust dataset, we define a child for a parent and not other way around. For example `papa lee` and `granny lee` should have `3` in `parent id` column etc. Please regenerate the data

Comment: yes, i would like to have 2 children for same parents, so all both lines coming from `sandra knight` and `jeffrey knight` should be solid

Comment: Adjusted per your request

Comment: not sure if you have updated data correctly, i have added the screenshot. Please check your query and make changes if required.

Comment: A directed graph (acyclic or not) is much more general and complex to handle than a simple tree graph. I'm fairly certain that this particular visual cannot handle the many-to-many relationships you're wanting. You'll need something specifically designed to handle that kind of structure.

Comment: @AlexisOlson is there any other custom visualization that i can use?

Comment: There are some network visuals but the ones I've seen don't give much control over the shape of the graph (and thus wouldn't look like a hierarchy any more).